# Would the following be a legal way to implement cascacding parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I know this may be a very newbie question, but I'd like to use a query in SSRS with CASE and WHEN/THEN statements. But would this be allowable? picture is attached:
[image]

Here's a screen of my SSRS, so I have 6 parameters - and the last one, ClientResponseRange, is hidden and depends on ResponseRange. For all cases but one, ClientResponseRange just gets exactly the same parameters passed to it that ResponseRange got :

[image]

So then here are the pictures of these params:

[image][image]

Comment: nope...........not if you are trying to test individual members of the comma separated string

Comment: @MitchWheat - Hmm, actually the whole comma separated string  is one text chunk, and in the back-end there's a stored proc. that takes care of commaas - so I just need to pass it into the SPROC as somethin like '20,21,22'

Comment: Can you explain what the problem you are trying to solve is?

Comment: @MitchWheat - Sure, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a dummy query or built in vb code that takes in the `@ResponseRange` and spits out the string you want.

Example sql:

```
Select case when :ResponseRange= '3' then null
            Else :ResponseRange
       End as out1
```

Then you should set the default values of the `@ClientResponseRange` by this query using the "Get values from a query" option.